# Replacing glimagesink with ximagesink after glshader - what conversion is needed?

Tags: gstreamer

I have a complex gstreamer pipeline that doesn't work.  The essence of the problem can be reduced to this simple pipeline working fine (gstl is alias for gst-launch-1.0):

```
gstl  videotestsrc pattern=11 ! glupload ! glshader fragment="..." ! glimagesink
```

(Never mind the shader details, replaced with just ... here.)  But we'd like to use ximagesink or autovideosink to display the video.  Simply changing it leads to a non-functioning pipeline.

WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link glfiltershader0 to ximagesink0

So, since half of all problems like that can be solved by jamming in a 'videoconvert' or 'autovideoconvert' between the grumpy units, I tried that.

```
gstl  videotestsrc pattern=11 ! glupload ! glshader fragment="..." ! ximagesink
```

This does not fix the problem.

What do I need to put between the glshader and ximagesink to do the right conversion to get video flowing through the pipe?

Comment: I never used gl plugins but I'm assuming glupload transfers the data to gpu memory looking at the documentation https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-glupload.html

And imo you may need to use `gldownload` to transfer it back to local memory after `glshader` element.

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-gldownload.html

Comment: you could use glcolorscale (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-glcolorscale.html)

Comment: Yes, that works!   Make this comment an answer and you'll have a green checkmark.

Comment: None of the examples I looked at had 'gldownload' so I didn't know it existed.  Makes sense, though.